# Facebook Comment Box not working but worked before

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I was trying to implement a simple Facebook [social plugin comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) box onto  my website. The URL of the box is not static, since every post on my site has one of them, but is generated using PHP.

I got it working fine for a while, but suddenly it stopped doing so and now I can't get it back again. I'm not too familiar with Facebook development, so I might've made a mistake in the code.

Here's how I load the Facebook **[Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)** (I changed some fields for anonymity):

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : MY_ID,
          channelUrl : 'http://www.mysite.com/channel.php', 
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;

         js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
</script>
```

And here is how I initialize the **comment box**:

```
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_ID';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class='fb-comments' data-href='http://mysite.com/post?id=<?php echo $id; ?>' data-num-posts='4' data-width='470'></div>
```

Here's **channel.php:**

```
<?php
header("Pragma: public");
$cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

I pasted the scripts at the end of the page in the body. Right now, nothing is showing up at all— no errors, just blank. Any help about getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what error do you get? because the code seems to be right

i did run your code here and it is working http://www.fbrell.com/saved/3d28d7b2918058e73c5a3f2ae481bf4e

Comment: I don't get an error— the box simply remains invisible. Also, I think that the problem might be the way that I implement the Javascript SDK, since I've never worked with it before. I updated my post to also show the channel.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, but the whole thing was caused by a stupid mistake of mine: I had a Firefox addon that was blocking the commenting box. It actually works  fine. I apologize for my mistake.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler will you please tell us the name of that firefox addon

Comment: It's Disconnect, which is used to "stop major third parties from tracking the webpages you go to". However, it seems like it has been removed since (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disconnect/).